# Weird Windows Phone 8.1 issue

Tags: xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone-emulator

I am creating Windows Phone 8.1 app. I created whole with Windows Phone Emulator and Nokia Lumia 430 mobile Testing. App looks good and works perfectly.

But weird thing I show that when I gave to client. Phone which I am using for test and Windows Emulator have windows, back and search keys outside the screen where as Client Mobile (i.e.**Nokia Lumia 640 XL**) have on the screen. Due to that screen lower part of the screen cannot been seen.

I have seen that all apps are running above that panel but my app bottom part is getting cover by that panel in Nokia Lumia 640 XL

I wanted to know, how do you guys solve this issue.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue occurring on some phones with soft keys. You can simulate it in the 720p emulator (enable soft keys on the Sensors tab).

The post at http://blog.zumicts.com/usecorewindow-without-overlapping-navbar-and-appbar-winphone-8-1/ shows you how to fix this issue buy offsetting your Frame when soft keys are available.

Comment: Looks something promising solution, let implement it and let you know :)

Answer (score 0):

Giving a bottom margin in the `scrollviewer` might fix your issue .

```
<ScrollViewer margin="0,0,0,30">

</ScrollViewer>
```

I assume you are getting the issue only with the last item in the screen .

You need to edit the `ControlTempalte` to set margin for  `Scrollviewer/ScrollBar` if you are using `Listbox/LonglistSelctor`

Comment: not in only my page but also in Full Screen WebView Pages